# Is it acceptable to get fired for asking for personal leave?

Tags: termination, canada

I was recently let go (fired) from my employer, however, it was not due to my performance nor was it my attendance.

I needed a week off (unpaid) due to a family emergency and they thanked me for letting them know. Next day I receive an email from my boss' boss requesting that we speak.  We spoke over the phone and she passive aggressively fired me. I advised her that I had a family emergency and she told me not to worry about coming to work. I took it as a nice thing and told her I would let her know when my last day will be in an email (I needed to check the dates). She responded by saying not to bother coming back for the rest of the week...or ever.

I was confused so I told her I would be back in December and she clarified: No, don't worry about being back in December... or moving forward following your situation.

Two weeks later I received an Employment Insurance form in the mail indicating the end of my employment there. Is this a valid reason to terminate an employee?

By the way I always put my all into my work and my performance was over excellent. The management was never really a fan of me though, and favoritism played often in our team.

Comment: What country are you in? Are you an at will employee? If the answer to the latter question is yes, then yes she can fire you for this or any other reason and it will be valid and acceptable in her eyes.

Comment: You say a few days but then mention you would be back in December. That doesn't add up. A month or more leave can in no way be construed as a few days. Were you planning on starting the leave at the end of November or now/next week?

Comment: This really needs specifying your location and type of employment for this to be answerable.

Comment: Also, please clarify what an "EI form" is, or remove that part, if it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: At any rate asking whether something is "acceptable" or a "valid reason" to fire someone is not a good question for this site, because it's mostly subjective. You can ask what you can do about it, or how to avoid it, or if there are official regulations about it, but it needs to be a practical question. Right now this reads more like a rant.

Comment: If you think your employer is doing something illegal, you really should get what they say in writing (e.g. ask for an email stating the same). What if she just denies what she said or that the conversation happened at all and claims that you stopped showing up for work one day, and that was the reason for your termination?

Comment: It was a family emergency so it was indefinite how much time. I estimated a week. Sorry I said a few days but I think I actually asked for a week unpaid.

Comment: EI will be Employment Insurance, placing the asker in Canada.

Comment: "I needed a week off (unpaid) due to a family emergency.  I was confused so I told her I would be back in December " - Its Nov 2nd, December, is more than 28 days away.  So are you taking a week off or 4 weeks off?  If an employee asked for a week and I approved that leave, then came back to me shortly, and said they would get back to me when they could come back to work  3 weeks later I wouldn't be happy either.

Comment: Of course it's not a legitimate reason to fire you. It is mean-spirited and awful given that most people have to go through the illness and/or death of a loved one at some point in their lifetime.  One would hope that in such times employers can give a bit of slack. Sadly, that's not the case and even things like the FMLA (in the US) can't keep employers from getting rid of people anyway, they can just come up with an arbitrary "valid reason" for the termination.

Comment: since you are in Canada this is a pretty answerable question, if you can re-word it to ask a specific non-subjective question. In Ontario, if your employer has at least 50 employees, they are required to allow 10 days a year of unpaid emergency leave.  You may have legal recourse through your provincial government if there are similar requirements there. Consider asking what steps you can take against your employer, and include the size of the company and your province/territory

Comment: Yes my employer had about 200 employees

Comment: @CameronRoberts I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. The OP asked for a week's unpaid leave and "extended" it to a month. Even taking into account 5 day work week, public holidays, etc., that is at about 20 days of leave. Not sure how having 10 days of unpaid leave helps the OP in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In the US, employees are eligible to take FMLA leave if they have worked for their employer for at least 12 months, and have worked for at least 1,250 hours over the previous 12 months, and work at a location where at least 50 employees are employed by the employer within 75 miles.

Upon notifying your employer of a need for leave, the employer is required to take action to determine FMLA eligibility.  Not knowing your exact circumstances, I can't advise any further except that you should research Family Medical Leave Act (FMLA) and if you are interested in pursuing this, speak to a workplace/labor relations lawyer.

Sounds like a bad working environment anyway.  Were it me I'd sign up for unemployment and start hunting for a new employer.

Answer (score -3):

No reason is needed in most places (excluding according to comments parts of Europe). In fact giving a reason is worse than not giving one in many cases eg,. discrimination, personal issue etc,. so firing someone because you don't like white people is unacceptable and the (ex) employee could rip into you in many ways, but firing them without giving a reason isn't.

A CEO went on a business trip for a fortnight leaving his wife in charge. She fired every single halfway decent looking woman in the place. Nothing they could do about it because their looks was not the reason given for dismissal.

Comment: *"No reason is needed in most places."* Citation needed. In much of Europe, for example, you generally need a *very* good reason in order to fire an employee. Since OP doesn't say where they are located, assuming just risks muddying the waters.

Comment: In Europe, it is quite trivial to fire people. Just mark it as "due to productional or financial reasons" and that's it. I've never heard of any dismissal being cancelled if the company really isn't in financial or productional difficulties.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen yes, and the same applies anywhere I know of

Comment: @JuhaUntinen: In Germany, lawsuits to fight a firing are quite common, there is even a separate type of court for it ([Arbeitsgericht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeitsgericht)). And yes, it is possible to fire someone for production or financial reasons (_betriebsbedingte Kündigung_), but usually a substantial severance package is due.

Comment: @sleske you can sue over anything you want, but doesn't stop you being fired. Does your example mean they can keep showing up for work without being shown the door by security? Or just that they can legally protest being fired in an attempt to get paid off? I'll change my answer to exclude Europe.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen In some countries, if you fire for financial reasons you are barred from employing replacements for months, with all the obvious consequences this would have on the company.

Comment: @Kilisi: I'm no lawyer, but AFAIK you cannot show up for work if your employer refuses - but if you figth the firing, they may have to continue paying you. And if you fight a firing in court, the court can either decide the employer has to take you back, or award you a severance payment. Both happens in practice, but usually cases are settled with a payment.

Comment: @Kilisi If you legally protest and win (at least in my country), your employer could even be forced to take you back with full pay and responsibilities, even paying a big fine for unjustly firing you.

Comment: @BgrWorker would have to be very silly employers to let themselves get in that situation. I'm assuming competence on the part of the employer here.

Comment: @Kilisi You'll be surprised to know that I've seen multiple cases of this. Basically, work laws and rights are a mess here. There are multiple facets you can sue for, and the one that have the better lawyer usually wins. That's also why companies usually make lots of short-term contracts, so they can lay off someone by just waiting for the contract to end, without additional complications.

Comment: @BgrWorker interesting info

Comment: @BgrWorker And countries in europe have legislated against that, forbidding multiple short term contracts in succession.